# Native base's Checkbox and radio button presentation not working

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am having problem with checkbox and radio button of native base. In checkbox, instead of check(tick) icon hyphen icon shows whereas for radio buttons shuffle icon shows up instead of cicle radio[image] button. Has anybody faced similar issues?? It was all good until last week. I dont know what has happened now. I have tried reinstalling vector icons,native base.But nothing worked.[[image: checkbox][1]]